# Android - Gaussian blur like effect - OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, grafika, gaussianblur

Where not specified this question is just building on top of the `CameraCaptureActivity` within the [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) project found on github.

It has a built in blur effect that utilises a 3x3 kernel

```
kernel = new float[] {
    1f/16f, 2f/16f, 1f/16f,
    2f/16f, 4f/16f, 2f/16f,
    1f/16f, 2f/16f, 1f/16f };
```

However this blur effect is not strong enough, im looking for something like what the gaussian effect can do on iOS with `UIVisualEffectView`, it looks something like this:

A nice smooth heavy blur effect but so far the best ive managed is this:

As you can see it is not nearly as smooth and also a bit squarish.

I achieved this by converting to a 5x5 kernel generated using this [handy tool](http://dev.theomader.com/gaussian-kernel-calculator/) with a sigma of 30 and kernel size of 5. It produces the following:

```
kernel = new float[] {
    0.039911f,  0.039978f,  0.04f,      0.039978f,  0.039911f,
    0.039978f,  0.040044f,  0.040067f,  0.040044f,  0.039978f,
    0.04f,      0.040067f,  0.040089f,  0.040067f,  0.04f,
    0.039978f,  0.040044f,  0.040067f,  0.040044f,  0.039978f,
    0.039911f,  0.039978f,  0.04f,      0.039978f,  0.039911f
};
```

In order to get the to work within the `Grafika` project i had to modify `KERNEL_SIZE` and `mTexOffset` within the `Texture2dProgram` class

`KERNEL_SIZE` is now `25` and `mTextOffset` is now calculated like so:

```
public void setTexSize(int width, int height) {

    float rw = 50.0f / width;
    float rh = 50.0f / height;

    float rw50 = rw * 0.5f;
    float rh50 = rh * 0.5f;

    mTexOffset = new float[] {
            -rw, -rh,   -rw50, -rh,     0f, -rh,    rw50, -rh,      rw, -rh,
            -rw, -rh50, -rw50, -rh50,   0f, -rh50,  rw50, -rh50,    rw, -rh50,
            -rw, 0f,    -rw50, 0f,      0f, 0f,     rw50, -0f,      rw, 0f,
            -rw, rh50,  -rw50, rh50,    0f, rh50,   rw50, rh50,     rw, rh50,
            -rw, rh,    -rw50, rh,      0f, rh,     rw50, rh,       rw, rh
    };
};
```

Does anyone have an suggestions on what i could modify to achieve an iOS like blur (i think iOS is also lightening pixels as well)? I think where i am really going wrong is the setTextSize() calculation, specifically the `50.0f` value, i have just plucked this from thin air and observed the effect it has

Comment: See `RenderScript` solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk, https://ssaurel.medium.com/create-a-blur-effect-on-android-with-renderscript-aa05dae0bd7d, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447630/how-to-use-the-renderscript-blurring-effect-without-artifacts (they are the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convolution with an actual blur kernel is a computationally intensive task, even on a GPU.  There are a few techniques that make it work better:

- The Gaussian kernel can be decomposed into X and Y components, which are computed separately.  This technique is used by image manipulation programs because it is relatively fast and accurate.
- Instead of using the Gaussian kernel, you can use Poisson disc sampling to blur the image.
- You can use a multi-pass Kawase filter as an approximation to a Gaussian filter.
- Sampling from lower resolution mip maps will result in better performance for a given subjective blur quality.
- You can sample from between texels in order to hijack texture interpolation and get more taps than you would otherwise get.

It will generally take some fine-tuning to get it to "look right" once you start making these tradeoffs.  A good summary is available at [An investigation of fast real-time GPU-based image blur algorithms](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/07/15/an-investigation-of-fast-real-time-gpu-based-image-blur-algorithms) (Filip S., 2014).